# Asymptotic estimation of an integral

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, definite-integrals

I have an integral of the form
$$
I = \int\limits_0^1\int\limits^{1}_{0} \exp\left(\dfrac{vt}{(u+v+1)^2 + v^2} - vt\right) dudv.
$$
I intend to prove
$$
I\leq c t^{-1}
$$
holds for the sufficiently large $t$, where $c$ is a positive constant independent of $t$.
By the way, the numerical integration shows that $c$ exists and is less than $9$.
Can anyone give me some hints or references to prove this estimation?

Comment: From the shape of the integrand, I guess it's possible to show that this integral is $\le e^{-at}$ for some small $a>0$.

Comment: @TravorLZH: Thanks for your answer. Maybe you're right, but I don't know how to prove it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In fact, very interesting problem; below I will provide some heuristic solution.
First, we notice that the main contribution to the integral come from the region near $v=0$ or $u=0$.
Indeed,
$$I=\int\limits_0^1\int\limits^{1}_{0} \exp\left(\dfrac{vt}{(u+v+1)^2 + v^2} - vt\right) dudv$$
$$=\int\limits_0^1\int\limits^{1}_{0} \exp\left(-vt\dfrac{2u+2v+u^2+2uv+v^2}{1+2(u+v)+u^2+2uv+v^2} \right) dudv$$
and the only zero of the power of the exponent is at $v=0$ or $u=0$.
Making the substitution $u=r\cos^2\phi$ and $v=r\sin^2\phi$, we get
$$\frac{vt}{(u+v+1)^2 + v^2} - vt=-vt\Big(1-\frac{1}{(1+u+v)^2+v^2}\Big)$$
$$=-r\sin^2\phi\Big(1-\frac{1}{(1+r)^2+r^2\sin^4\phi}\Big)$$
The main contribution to the integral comes from the region near $\,r\sin^2\phi=0$, so we can drop integration in the area $r>1$ and consider only a quarter-circle of the radius $r\leqslant1$. Given that $r\sin^2\phi\ll1$, we are also allowed to decompose the exponent power as
$$-r\sin^2\phi\Big(1-\frac{1}{(1+r)^2+r^2\sin^4\phi}\Big)=-r\sin^2\phi\Big(1-\frac{1}{(1+r)^2}\big(1-\frac{r^2\sin^4\phi}{(1+r)^2}\big)\Big)$$
$$=-r\sin^2\phi\Big(1-\frac{1}{(1+r)^2}\Big)-\frac{r^3\sin^6\phi}{(1+r)^4}\tag{1}$$
It is not difficult to show that the second term in (1) has a contribution to the asymptotics $\sim\,o\Big(\frac{1}{t}\Big)$, so we drop it. The jacobian of the change is $2r\sin\phi\cos\phi$, so after all manipulations we get for our integral
$$I\sim\int_0^1dr\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} e^{-rt\sin^2\phi\big(1-\frac{1}{(1+r)^2}\big)}2r\sin\phi\cos\phi\,d\phi=\int_0^1rdr\int_0^1e^{-rtx\big(1-\frac{1}{(1+r)^2}\big)}dx$$
Integrating over $x$ first and making some transformations,
$$=\frac{1}{t}\int_0^1\Big(1-e^{-rt\big(1-\frac{1}{(1+r)^2}\big)}\Big)\frac{(1+r)^2}{(1+r)^2-1}rdr$$
$$=\frac{1}{t}\int_0^1\Big(1-e^{-rt\big(1-\frac{1}{(1+r)^2}\big)}\Big)\Big(\frac{1}{2r}+1-\frac{1}{2(r+2)}\Big)dr$$
Integrating by part
$$=\frac{1}{t}\Big(\frac{\ln r}{2}+r-\frac{\ln (r+2)}{2}\Big)\Big(1-e^{-\frac{r^2t\,(2+r)}{(1+r)^2}}\Big)\,\bigg|_0^1$$
$$-\int_0^1\Big(\frac{\ln r}{2}+r-\frac{\ln (r+2)}{2}\Big)\frac{4+3r+r^2}{(1+r)^3}e^{-\frac{r^2t\,(2+r)}{(1+r)^2}}rdr\tag{2}$$
Analysis shows that we can simplify further, dropping the terms which do not contribute to the main asymptotics terms (the main contribution comes from the region near $r=0)$. Accomplishing this program, and making the substitution $z=r^2t$, we are left with
$$I\sim\frac{1}{t}\bigg(1-\frac{\ln3}{2}\Big)-\frac{1}{t}\int_0^t\Big(\ln\sqrt \frac{z}{t}-\ln\big(\sqrt \frac{z}{t}+2\big)\bigg)e^{-2z}dz\tag{3}$$
Expanding integration to $\infty$ (doing this, we drop exponentially small terms), and using $\int_0^\infty\ln t\,e^{-t}dt=-\gamma$ (the Euler's constant), we finally get the leading asymptotics terms
$$\boxed{\,\,I(t)\sim\frac{\ln t}{4\,t}+\frac{1}{t}\Big(1-\frac{\ln3}{2}+\frac{3\ln2}{4}+\frac{\gamma}{4}\Big)\,\,}\tag{4}$$
We see that the leading term is $\frac{\ln t}{t}$ in fact, but we also kept the term $\sim\frac{1}{t}$, which makes a substantial contribution for any reasonable $t\gg1$.

The numeric check shows that the approximation works rather well:
$\displaystyle t=10 \,\,\,\qquad I=0.1566..\qquad \,\,\,\,\text {approximation}=0.1690...$
$\displaystyle t=100 \qquad I=0.02201..\qquad \,\,\text {approximation}=0.02266...$
$\displaystyle t=1000 \,\,\quad I=0.002818..\qquad \text {approximation}=0.002841...$
$\displaystyle t=100000 \,\, I=0.000039906..\,\, \text {approximation}=0.000039930...$

Comment: Amazing, thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: The numerical results support Svyatoslav's approximation. A crude estimate is $$
I(t) \le \int_0^1\!\! {\int_0^1 {\exp \left( {\frac{{vt}}{{(u + 1)^2 }} - vt} \right)dudv} }  \le \frac{5}{4}\int_0^1 {\frac{{dv}}{{vt + 1}}}  = \frac{5}{4}\frac{{\log (t + 1)}}{t},
$$ which also suggests (but of course does not imply) an asymptotic form of $\log(t)/t$.